# Restoring sidebar in VF beyond setting sidebar="true"

Tags: visualforce, sidebar

I have two VF pages that load within a Visualforce tab - a custom search() page which leads to another to create Cases/custom records/log a call etc.  These have worked without requiring a sidebar for some time.  With a new phone provider, I need to display the standard sidebar so that the CTI component can be used for call control.

The sidebars on each have been suppressed, but setting sidebar="true" is not restoring their functionality.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" 
sidebar="true" 
id="consolePage"
cache="false" 
controller="NxCSHIConsoleController" 
action="{!processPage}"
standardstylesheets="true" 
tabStyle="Account"
title="Customer Support Console">
```

Is there anything inherent in a Visualforce tab that suppresses them?  Nothing in the tab settings appears that way, unlike what you see in a custom button's Behavior attributes, for instance.

The only other thing that comes to mind is that a style could possibly be suppressing them (although I would hope that the style would be applied so as to accommodate the sidebar, not override) - this is the style that is applied to the main body of the page:

```
.ui-layout-center {
    border-top: 0;
    padding: 0 20px 20px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 900px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First check setup > customize > ui "show sidebar on all pages" (or similar).

If you see the sidebar on other vf pages it could have been suppressed by custom css in the vf page or by javascript.

Take firebug or open the developer tools in webkit-browser and inspect a page where you see the sidebar. Try to find the sidebar markup on the page where it's invisible and check for display:none

If there isn't sidebar markup at all, the elements could have been removed by JS. Search your VF code or included javascript for selectors which might match the sidebar.

Comment: "Show Custom Sidebar Components on All Pages" is checked; one page has JS, one does not.  JS tools it is - thanks!

Comment: Cool. If it's solved consider to vote and accept the answer or let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: That may very well be the correct answer; it's going to take me a while to parse the log (especially when it continuously updates) to locate the relevant selector(s).